# What is the difference between Java Deployment Toolkit Plug-in and deployJava.js?

Tags: deployment, toolkit

I was reading this article:

http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/deployment_toolkit.xml

and I get confused about the purpose and use of the DT Plug-in and the deployJava.js.

I always believe that the Deployment Toolkit is the set of functions of the deployJava.js file (like this link says: http://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/entry/deployment_toolkit_101) but according to the article there are two parts of the Deployment Toolkit: the Plug-in and the interface for the developer.

I'm asking about all of this because the deployJava.js fails to detect the appropriate version of Java in some of the machines of our users and I was wondering if the DT Plug-in could help us improve the detection, but I don't know how exactly it detects the Java version and when it does it or how can I use it to solve detection problems?

Most of this doubts are driven by the question in the article:

*"**Does deployJava.js work if the Java DT Toolkit plug-in is disabled?**
Yes, deployJava.js contains some pure JavaScript functions, which will continue to work even if the Java DT Toolkit plug-in is disabled."*

So... why do I need the deployJava.js if the DT Plug-in exists or vice versa?

Any help on this matter would be very appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone has doubts about it, I've posted this question in the oracle forum and this was the reply:

> Deployment toolkit is combination of native library and javascript
>   helpers. javascript is the only official public API to native library.
>
> JRE is installed with DT native library that is left on the system if
>   JRE is uninstalled.  As of now DT native library is only available on
>   Windows.
>
> Javascript helper functions use native library if it is available but
>   many actions can be performed (with degraded accuracy, etc.) even if
>   native library is not present.
>
> Note that there is new Javascript APIs for DT as alternative to
>   deployJava.js. it is called
>   [dtjava.js|http://download.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/deployment/deployment_toolkit.htm#BABJHEJA]
>   and is primary API for JavaFX applications. However, it also supports
>   pure Java apps and likely will be main JS API for DT going forward
>   (some more testing and bug fixing may be needed).
>
> Hope this helps to clarify the relationship.

Thxs to igor

Link to oracle post: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=9932788#9932788